# Running protractor tests on localhost with VirtualHost configurations?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, protractor

I'm running a tutorial locally at `dev.angular.com`, with corresponding virtualhost and hosts file configurations.  I'm able to execute Jasmine unit tests, but not Protractor end-to-end tests because it always looks for the `localhost:8000/app/index.html` URL.

Is there any way to re-configure Protractor to use `dev.angular.com` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the configuration file. There is a property called `baseUrl`. Change it to:

```
baseUrl: 'http://dev.angular.com'
```